# PPO model performance on Tensorboard vs Reality

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I've created multiple environments for stock trading. They are quite simple, I've been using episodes of 11 steps. The observation is something like this:

```
[[price_tminus2,price_diff_tminus3_&_tminus2],[price_tminus1,price_diff_tminus2_&_tminus1],
[price_t,price_diff_tminus1_&_t]]
```

When making env.reset() I create a list of possible actions with pairs [action,volume] (I am making this env first discrete and later I am going to turn it into continuous). The model will choose an index from that list, that will correspond to what it will do in the environment. My problem is this: although on tensorboard the mean episode reward converges to the maximum possible for that episode when I try to use model.predict() directly for each step to check the performance on one episode it shows very suboptimal performance, a totally different reward. How is this possible? I run the episode like this:

```
eval_env = gym.make('stockbuyselln-v0',df = df_sin, frame_bound=(5,16), window_size=3, initCash = 1)
obs = np.array(eval_env.reset())
while True: 
    obs = eval_env.get_observation()
    action, _states = PPO_model.predict(obs)
    obs, rewards, done, truncated, info = eval_env.step(action)
    if done:
        #print("info", info)
        break
plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
eval_env.render_all()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I found that not having the eval_env wrapped in a Monitor wrapper can cause variations in reward, but after doing that the problem stays. I also used stable_baselines3.common.evaluation.evaluate_policy(model, env, n_eval_episodes=10, deterministic=True), where I get the same results that I was getting from tensorboard

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, it had to do to with having the eval_env vectorized with dummyvecenv as it is done in training. Check the code for evaluate_policy of stable baselines 3 for a deeper understanding.